# Android Studio AssertionError while building project

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I've been fighting with Android Studio and Gradle all day.  My project originally was created in Eclipse, then migrated to IntelliJ, and now Android studio.  It has the old project structure for example.  I ended up following through Google's migration guide for how to convert the project to a Gradle structure.  After much pain I was able to get Gradle installed and successfully built my project by calling `gradle buildDebug`.

I'm trying to get it so that I can click the Run button in Android Studio and get the behavior it previously had (build the project, load onto device, open on device).  I also need to get back interactive debugging.  Whenever I try to click the button it does nothing and eventually grays itself out.  I notice it throws an `AssertionError` with this stacktrace:

```
null
java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.invokeGradleTasks(GradleTasksExecutor.java:229)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.run(GradleTasksExecutor.java:184)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:373)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:435)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:152)
```

I have seen other posts for `AssertionError` but not for this line.  Right now I'm building with a custom shell script I made to execute Gradle and fire off the ADB command.  I'd really like this integrated with Android Studio though.  Any ideas?  Is this just a bug?  Is there a way to launch interactive debugging with Android Studio using `adb` and the command line?  If I had that option I probably wouldn't care so much.  Thanks.

Using Android Studio 0.4.0 and Gradle 1.9

Comment: That assertion is in the guts of some Gradle execution code and indicates something weird is going on. I'd recommend filing a bug at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug and include more details on the directory structure of your project, and more important, attach your log file (File menu > Show log)

Comment: @ScottBarta Thanks.  I submitted a report using the prompt in Android Studio itself.  Think I should fill out one for your link as well?  I figure this issue is due to a bug, but I see people posting lots of workarounds and thought there would be one for this.

Comment: I don't see the issue in the bug database.

Comment: I have the same error. I just downloaded the entire project from SVN, the "sync project files with gradle" and then tried to build, then I get the above error.
The EXACT same project is running on the same computer, but from another location (folder). I did this as a test to see how easy it is to put on SVN and install elsewhere. Apparently, not so easy...

Answer (score 0):

Try my solution here and see if it works for you:
[android studio 0.4.2: Gradle project sync failed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error)

Do you have JAVA_HOME and GRADLE_HOME env variables set up correctly ? (ie pointing to the correct locations?)

Do you get the same error if you create a new project ?

Comment: Forgot to reply to this.  Not really sure how it was fixed.  I think a new version of AS came out and fixed it when I clicked Import Gradle Project.  Thanks for the suggestions.