# android studio 0.4.2: Gradle project sync failed error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After updating to 0.4.2 I get this error when opening a project:
'Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work proprerly'

The event log shows this:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:95)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:149)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:106)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:100)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:143)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ActionAwareConsumerConnection.run(ActionAwareConsumerConnection.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.run(LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2014-01-12 02:57:48,886 [  33025]   INFO - .BaseProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at 'C:/android/workspace_studio/Noggle' 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:170)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$000(GradleProjectResolver.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$1.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:117)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$1.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:373)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:436)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:153)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read below process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:95)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:149)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:106)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:100)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:143)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ActionAwareConsumerConnection.run(ActionAwareConsumerConnection.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.run(LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2014-01-12 02:57:48,893 [  33032]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:185)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:373)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:436)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:153)

2014-01-12 02:57:48,895 [  33034]   WARN - .project.GradleProjectImporter -  
2014-01-12 02:57:48,895 [  33034]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectImporter - A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.


Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2014-01-12 02:57:48,941 [  33080]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Port/ID: 21325/Maven3ServerImpl5ed05101 
2014-01-12 02:57:49,424 [  33563]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/remote-servers.xml file is null 
2014-01-12 02:57:50,185 [  34324]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 13482 ms
```

Version 0.4.1 was behaving very well for me.

Comment: Update: Gave up trying to get version 0.4.2 to work. Tried just about everything like disabling non essential running processes, increasing swap file size. Re-installed 0.4.1 and the project loads up perfectly.

Comment: i think it is just a bug in AS. i upgraded to 0.4.2 and my project does not work too, but i get a different error. With AS 0.3.x everything worked well

Comment: same here, updating to 0.4.2 also broke everything in my case...
It has nothing to do with memory usage : I've got 8 gig of memory and I have 3.5 gig free atm, so not having enough memory to start up a JVM is bullocks...

Actually it might have something to do with Gradle versions, I looked into the error log and found this :

Comment: just now tried with the simple app with AS and it broke as suggested. II think eclipse is the right way to go (for now)...

Comment: Similar issue, but nothing is returned in the Event Log

Answer (score 293, accepted):

I'm assuming I can answer my own question....
This worked for me.

1. File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
2. Shutdown Android Studio
3. Rename/remove .gradle folder in the user home directory
4. Restart Android Studio let it download all the Gradle stuff it needs
5. Gradle build success !
6. Rebuild project.... success !

Out of curiousity I compared the structure of the old .gradle and the new one... they were pretty different !

So I'll see how 0.4.2 goes :)

Comment: I tried deleting build.gradle from same level than src and it didn't worked. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Just follow the step by step instructions above and it should work if you had the same problem as I did.

Comment: "Rename .gradle file out of the way". I tried changing its name for example to "___build.gradle" and it didn't work. What did you mean to?

Comment: I renamed mine to old.gradle and it worked. You said earlier that you deleted the build.gradle file from the src directory. I didn't do this as the file is needed in the build. Try creating a new project, if you get the "Gradle project sync failed" error then follow the steps above and report back.

Comment: Instruction worked for me, but I had to remove/rename ".gradle" folder from user home directory, not the one placed in project workspace.

Comment: That should make it clearer Ramps. Have edited my instruction to reflect this. Cheers

Comment: Eventually this worked for me as well, had to try a couple of times though, so you might have to persist a little.

Comment: In my project there are three main folders; .idea, app & gradle.  The gradle folder is the one I renamed to old.gradle, but it never solves the problem.  I've tried twice.  Any advice?

Comment: KFP the gradle folder that you need to rename is the one in your user directory, NOT the one in your project. See Ramps comment above. Also, my .gradle directory in my user directory looks like this C:\Users\Carlos Taylor\.gradle. That is the one you have to rename/remove.

Comment: This worked for me without step 3. I had tried a few solutions before that so it might have affected the process, but this step may not be necessary.

Comment: First try with only making **Invalidate cache and restart**.
Sometimes this issue solved only with only making this trick

Answer (score 72):

I had the same problem, but finally I could solve it forever.

1. Delete `gradle` and `.gradle` folders from your project folder.
2. In Android Studio: Open your project then: **File -> settings -> compiler -> gradle**: enable `offline mode`
   *Note: In relatively newer Android Studios, **Offline mode** has been moved to gradle setting.*
   [image]
3. Close your project: **File -> close project**
4. Connect to the Internet and open your project again then let Android Studio downloads what it wants

If success then `:)`
else

5. If you encounter `gradle project sync failed` again please follow these steps:
6. Download the latest gradle package from [this directory](http://services.gradle.org/distributions)
7. Extract it and put it somewhere (for example f:\gradle-1.10)
8. Go to your Android Studio and load your project then open **File->Settings->gradle**, in this page click on `Use local gradle distribution`
9. Type your gradle folder address there
   [image]

Congratulation  you are done!

Comment: This is really work for me.I have just followed the first step and it turn out to be OK. Many Thanks and hope help others.

Comment: Please update gradle link to its folder `http://services.gradle.org/distributions/` instead of file. current gradle is 2.3

Comment: In Android Studio 1.5.1, **Files > settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools, Gradle > Offline work**

Answer (score 16):

same here, updating to 0.4.2 also broke everything in my case...
It has nothing to do with memory usage : I've got 8 gig of memory and I have 3.5 gig free atm, so not having enough memory to start up a JVM is bullocks...

Actually it might have something to do with Gradle versions, I looked into the error log and found this :

> 2014-01-14 09:00:30,918 [  61112]   WARN -
>   nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Project is using an old version of
>   the Android Gradle plug-in. The minimum supported version is 0.7.0.
>   Please update the version of the dependency
>   'com.android.tools.build:gradle' in your build.gradle files.
>
> You are using Gradle version 1.8, which is not supported. Please use
>   version 1.9. Please point to a supported Gradle version in the
>   project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if
>   applicable.) 
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException:
>   Project is using an old version of the Android Gradle plug-in. The
>   minimum supported version is 0.7.0. Please update the version of the
>   dependency 'com.android.tools.build:gradle' in your build.gradle files

-

> You are using Gradle version 1.8, which is not supported. Please use
>   version 1.9.
>
> Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle
>   settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)

OK, I fixed it myself...
In the project directory go to /gradle/wrapper directory and edit the gradle-wrapper properties file to this :

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip
```

After open your project in Android Studio and select the build.gradle file in the /src directory and edit it to this :

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
```

***After fixing it like this I discovered this article :
http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released***

Comment: TiGer, your solution worked for me.  I did not need to consult the article.  Thank you.

Comment: This sounds promising. Will have another crack at 0.4.2 and get back.

Comment: Still no success with 0.4.2  The project loads and Gradle starts to build but stops with the 'Gradle project sync failed." error. The log file shows this: 2014-01-17 00:19:22,809 [  89902]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip'.

Comment: Thanks ! I personnally changed it to http\.../gradle-1-9-bin.zip and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

1. Open File-> Settings
2. Choose Gradle
3. Mark "Use local grandle distribution" and select the path of grandle home 
   for ex: C:/Users/high_hopes/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.1-all/27drb4udbjf4k88eh2ffdc0n55/gradle-2.1.1
   then choose service directory path C:/Users/high_hopes/.gradle
4. Apply all changes
5. Open File-> invalidate caches/ restart ...
6. Select Just Restart

Answer (score 5):

After reporting the problem on the Android Studio feedback site, they found a solution for me. I am now using Gradle 1.10 and Android Studio 0.4.3.

Here is the link to the page with a description of how I fixed mine:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65219

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

I found one answer on the net and it worked for me, thus here it is:

When you get the gradle project sync failed error, with error details:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM  Could not reserve enough
>   space for object heap  Error: Could not create the Java Virtual
>   Machine.  Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Then, on Windows, please go to:

Control Panel > System > Advanced(tab) > Environment Variables > System Variables > New:

Variable name `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and Variable value `-Xmx512M`

Save it, restart AS. It might work this time, as it did for me.

Source: http://www.savinoordine.com/android-studio-gradle-windows-7/

Answer (score 3):

I am facing this problem many times from last few days, the answer above works perfectly fine.  I was looking for the exact reason for this problem and in my case I found slow internet or no internet on your machine(assuming you are taking project to windows from mac, that may not be required).

I've noticed while doing build it stopped fetching a URL(http://*.maven.org/*). I don't  know why android studio doing these things again, but that seems to be the only problem in my case.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are upgrading to v1.0 of Android Studio and see the error Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard', If you are using version 0.14.0 or higher of the gradle plugin, you should replace "runProguard" with "minifyEnabled" in your build.gradle files. i.e.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: Was actually about to delete my small project on which this error occured. Saved me an hour of programming. :)

Answer (score 2):

After following Carlos steps I ended up deleting the

C:\Users\MyPath.AndroidStudioPreview Directory

Then re imported the project it seemed to fix my issue completely for the meanwhile, And speedup my AndroidStudio

Hope it helps anyone

Answer (score 2):

I have Android Studio 0.8.9 and after hours on forums the thing that finally worked for me was to manually download Gradle (latest version) then go to: C:\Users\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.12-all\\ and replace the local archive with the recently downloaded archive and also replace the extracted data; after restarting Android Studio... he did some downloadings and builds and all sorts of stuff, but it finally worked.. Good Luck people!

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me with Android Studio 1.0.2:

File -> Settings-> Gradle Set 'Use default Gradle wrapper.'

The other methods didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using Android Studio, but had same problem. I had to update the latest java jdk and set the JAVA_HOME to that jdk.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I deleted the android repository from android sdk manager and reinstalled it. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Load Project:>Build, execution, Deployment:>(Check on)compiler Independent modules in parllel.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

seems fairly clear-cut: your OS can't find enough RAM to start a new Java process, which is in this case the Gradle builder. Perhaps you don't have enough RAM, or not enough swap, or you have too many other memory-hungry processes running at the same time.

Comment: I had no problems with version 0.4.1 though. I could have Chrome running with 8-10 tabs open as well as a Genymotion emulator instance.

Comment: Also, I just fired up Eclipse 4.2.2 and it loads the project fine. I know that AS may probably have a lot more overhead but my workspace in  Eclipse has about 15 projects loaded at the same time! Seems to me like AS 0.4.2 has gone a step backward in memory management compared to 0.4.1 and overall cannot compare to Eclipse at this point in time IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I started my project and there was not enough RAM for gradle. I searched a solution for an hour including the variants given above, but then I just closed my browser and rebooted my IDE. Interesting that if you run browser or a game after successful starting IDE and project it still works properly. Hope this solution will be useful for somebody.
p.s. sorry for my English knowledge (it`s from school).

Comment: You might want to say how you know there was not enough RAM for gradle and the results of the other things you tried.

Comment: I just tried more hard solutions, but solved my problem in easy way and hoped that it will help to somebody else. Each time I run AndroidStudio I must close all applications in order not to have this error.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove `.gradle` from user, paste, and verify update in Android Studio and it will work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I always remove the .gradle folder from %USERS% folder and start the studio again. When starting the IDE it downloads gradle again with all the dependencies again.
Its work PERFECT.

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran into the same error, however, i was using Android Studio 1.0.2. What i did tot fix the problem was that i started a project with minimum SDK 4.4 (API 19) so when i checked the version i noticed that at File->ProjectStructure->app i found Android 5 as a compile SDK Version. I changed that back to 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this error along with:
"Error:compileSdkVersion android-21 requires compiling with JDK 7"

For me, the solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689513/errorcompilesdkversion-android-21-requires-compiling-with-jdk-7), where I had to update the JDK location in the project structure.