# Setting up Android Studio but how?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am pretty new to the android programming. I had programmed a test app 1 year ago on eclipse. Now there is android studio and I wanted to try this because it looked nice and useful.

After installing, I ran into some problems even if everybody said its so easy to do this... It wasn't for me until now! but that's my personal luck, i always run into some weird issues :)

What I've done until now:

- I have downloaded JDK **`(jdk-7u51-windows-i586)`** and installed it
- I have downloaded and installed Android Studio (AS) + upgrade to **AS-Version 0.4.6**.
- I have set JDK_HOME under sysvars to **`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51`**

First running **`AS`** said I'm using the wrong supportversion... Didn't know what exactly it was
then I tried to debug my error with
`gradlew clean build` in console.

tried to change

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0' <===
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

into

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1' <===
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

which seems to solve my problems until there...

but is still have this error:

```
Gradle project sync failed. 
Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.
```

and

```
Gradle 'ProjectName' project refresh failed: 
A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I tried **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error)** with no results

Can someone help me with that?

**Additional informations:**

- **`Google Reposetory 6`** and **`Android Support Library 19.0.1`** are installed.
- Terminal (ProjectFolder): `gradlew clean build`

  Results:

  `Ran lint on variant release: 12 issues found`

  `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`
- Gradle Version: `gradle-1.10-all`

Comment: What are the errors you're seeing when this happens?

Comment: I wrote them in my post. last 2 errors

Comment: can you please update which version of gradle are you using in your build.gradle files ? Also check default gradle wrapper selected in File > Settings > Gradle .

Comment: updated, its the `1.10-all` and yes default wrapper is checked. where can i see the used gradle file ? i have several build.gradle files...

Comment: I had the same problem with the same error message that you are getting. Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error. Also I think you need to have a GRADLE_HOME sysvar defined Unless you have done it already and didn't mention it in your question). Good luck.

Comment: actually i just delete JAVA_HOME from the ENV and it seemed to solve the problem :D and i read the post you just gave me befor

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use automatic gradle magic you have to download first google repository and android support repository shrough SDK manager (an icon on the top of AS widow - android with down arrow).

Comment: i know whats the sdk manager :) both installed, still having this issue (GR6 and ASL19.0.1)