# Error running MyActivity: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android Studio and I have just created a new project with only one Activity with fragments(Android studio created that), and when I ran the MyActivity.java , error occurs:

```
Error running MyActivity: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again.
```

Nothing more in my event log.

I have no idea why it is, and [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error) did not helps.

One clue is that Gradle project sync in progress is flowing all the time , just after I restart the Studio.

Comment: can you post your log ... and which version of studio you are using?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21168562/1442541

Comment: You can find a answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error/21168562#21168562

Comment: did you updated your sdk?

Comment: You should not run MainActivity . you should run app that contains MainActivity.

Answer (score 8):

1. Goto File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
2. Shutdown Android Studio
3. Rename/remove .gradle folder in the user home directory
4. Restart Android Studio (It will download gradle metadata and data)
5. Gradle build succeed
6. Rebuild project
7. Done

Answer (score 0):

The exact same error message also pops up if there is a syntax-error inside your AndroidManifest.xml file. So if the above won't work - which it didn't for me - then check the AndroidManifest.xml syntax. That will save you thousands of frustrating hours.