# Gradle error after importing projects from eclipse

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting this error in Android Studio after i've imported a project from eclipse

```
Error:Could not read cache value from'C:\Users\Username\.gradle\daemon\1.12\registry.bin'.
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: It says: Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality(e.g editing, debugging will not work properly.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21996772/1841194

Comment: possible duplicate of [android studio 0.4.2: Gradle project sync failed error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exit Android Studio, delete the `.gradle` directory at the path listed in the error message, and restart.

Comment: Each time I try to delete or rename .gradle directory, Explorer crashes. I found the problem comes from registry.bin, which I can't even right click on ! I have to reboot to fix this, would you have any idea how I could manage it quicker ?

Comment: @DanChaltiel Same thing is happening with me. Please tell me so if you found any solution.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a old post. But instead of deleting .gradle directory, you just need to delete **registry.bin.lock**. You will find this in the same directory where registry.bin is. This will save a lot of your time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just go **C:\Users\Username.gradle\daemon\1.12** directory and delete all files on that directory. then restart Android Studio. that should work