# How can I change Android Developer to find Java JDK 7 when it just can't seem to find it?

Tags: java, android

Firstly thanks for looking at this. I'm completely new to Android development (any development for that matter) and have downloaded and installed Android Studio. I followed the quick set up yet get this error:

*Error:compileSdkVersion android-21 requires compiling with JDK 7*

Opening the SDK settings I get told the directory path where JDK is is as follows:

*/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home*

This then appear to me to be JDK v6. So I downloaded JDK 7 from here|:

*http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html*

Which was this file:

*jdk-7u75-macosx-x64.dmg*

and I then installed it. However my machine just can't seem to find it. If I check what version of Java is installed using the terminal I get this:

*Marks-iMac-2:~ remarked$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-ea-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b07, mixed mode)*

Which shows to me v7. My problem is I just can't seem to locate this on my machine or then change the directory path as above to a JDK 7. I seem to have fallen at the first hurdle.

Can anyone please help?

**Thank you again.** My Mac is as follows:

Model Name: iMac
  Model Identifier: iMac9,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed:  2.93 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache: 6 MB
  Memory:   8 GB
System Version: OS X 10.10.1 (14B25)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 14.0.0
  Boot Volume:  Macintosh HD

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689513/errorcompilesdkversion-android-21-requires-compiling-with-jdk-7 .. it may help you

Comment: The Oracle JDK is no longer the suggested JDK for Android. For Java 7, it's now the OpenJDK that's recommended by Google for Android. That being said, that's not what's causing your problem right now. The link from Ichigo should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks guys, both of great help and problem now resolved with JDK 8 running. Cheers!!