# How can I set my compileSDKversion to support Java 1.6

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

I get the error:

```
Error:(3, 22) compileSdkVersion android-22 requires compiling with JDK 7
```

I am using a `Mac` running `OSX 10.6` so `JDK 7` isn't supported. Is there a way I can change the compileversion to one that can use `JDK 6`? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your target android sdk version to 21 or above it will require Java 7.

If you cannot use JDK 7 you can set your target sdk version to 20 or below. However, I would caution against this, if you are going to be building apps that will be in distributed on the play store it is a good idea to be using Java 7 and targeting version 21.

You can see more information about upgrading to using JDK 7 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689513/errorcompilesdkversion-android-21-requires-compiling-with-jdk-7)