# Gradle fails to build

Tags: android, build, gradle

I've got this error below:

```html
"could not initialize org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.internal.noopPluginResolver"
```

What I've to do?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

Shutdown Android Studio

Rename/remove .gradle folder in the user home directory

Restart Android Studio let it download all the Gradle stuff it needs

Gradle build success !

Rebuild project.... success !

FROM : [Another question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error)