# Gradle project sync failed?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, project

When I started up my project this morning it randomly gave me a message saying `Gradle project sync failed. Basic Functionality(eg. editing, debugging) will not work properly.` in Android Studio. I looked at other answers that people had put up for this problem but they haven't been working. I invalidated my chaches/restarted my project but no luck. I also deleted my .gradle folder from my project folder and still no luck. If any of you guys could help me that would be awesome! This didn't happen yesterday when I was working on the project or anything, I wonder why its happening now. Oh yea it also says this as a gradle message: `Error:C:\Users\Dave\.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\settings_ad4t0wp5ikihzl1y1o83b5sbw\SettingsScript\buildscript\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)` :

Thanks again for anyone who reads this/ can help!

Comment: Hard to say, but what if you try to delete the gradle folder in your userprofile (C:\Users\Dave\.gradle), and then launch `gradlew` from your AS console (Alt+F12)?

Comment: I deleted my Gradle folder from (C:/Users/Dave/.gradle) just now, but how do I launch the gradlew? thanks!

Comment: open your project, find gradlew and launch it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had experience similar **sync failed** problem with gradle based android project (**in Android Studio 1.1.0**). I solved this problem **without deleting** ***.gradle*** from my user directory, 
    steps I followed was

1. Go to File -> Settings -> Compiler(Gradle Based Android Project)
2. Change VM options to `-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`.
3. Click Apply -> OK and then tap on `Try Again` option in sync failed message to **clean build** the project.

Works like charm!!

**UPDATE - 1** : For **Android Studio 1.3**, *Compiler* option mentioned in above Step-1 is present inside tab **Build, Execution, Deployment**.

Comment: I use Android Studio 1.3 and there isn't any VM options in Compiler.

Comment: In Compiler setting, I tick Sync project with Gradle before building and it's worked.

Answer (score 3):

There is a file - "cache.properties" that gradle creates for you, upon first time inception of any project. The path for this file is "~Home_Directory\.gradle\2.2.1\taskArtifacts". You may find this path in your home directory. So basically, this file - "cache.properties" is missing from the "taskArtifacts" folder.

One of the solution that worked for me is to copy file - "cache.properties" from any test project of yours to this project that's currently experiencing an issue.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I had to choose using the Default Gradle Wrapper instead of local.
<< SETTINGS -->/ BUILD TOOLS --> Gradle  -->  radio button switch...   >>

It has helped me to fix the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar kind of problem earlier!

But don`t know after rebuild the project and cleaning it, it worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate dependency cache by running

```
gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies
```

from project root and then re-import your project. Worked for me once.

Comment: Im knew to this kind of thing. How do I get to my project root? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

May be you have put Android Studio into offline mode. To fix it, go to Preferences -> Gradle and ensure that the "Offline work" checkbox is not checked.

Than do

1. File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
2. Shutdown Android Studio
3. Rename/remove .gradle folder in the user home directory
4. Restart Android Studio let it download all the Gradle stuff it needs

[android studio 0.4.2: Gradle project sync failed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the folder C:\Users\.gradle and reopening the android studio solved my problem