# Error:BUG! exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit 'ijinit3_3j63o58w049ppu98go17wj3n4' unsupported Target TYPE_PARAMETER

Tags: android

I am new to android studio ,so whenever i try to create a new project this error shows up

"Error:BUG! exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit 'ijinit3_3j63o58w049ppu98go17wj3n4' unsupported Target TYPE_PARAMETER"

When i searched for the file with name 'ijinit3_3j63o58w049ppu98go17wj3n4'
i found it inside  " C:\Users\hai.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\ijinit3_3j63o58w049ppu98go17wj3n4" so there must be A problem with gradle,i have no idea what this gradle thing is ,So someone please help me!!

**Myapplication build.gradle code-**

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

**app/build.gradle code-**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
  }

 dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+' 
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])}
```

anything else is reqd ???

Comment: Have you solved this ?

Comment: Follow this link :Answer of "abforce" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error

Answer (score -1):

update your jdk version and it will work