# How to regenerate build.gradle file after deleting

Tags: android, build.gradle

I got an error with my Android project: `Gradle project sync failed error`, and then I searched the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error). However, I deleted wrong file(build.gradle instead of .gradle in the user home directory). So how do I generate build.gradle file in Android Studio again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your IDE and just create a file called `build.gradle`in the root folder if you deleted the top-level file, or inside a module if you deleted it.

It is a text file where you have to write your script.

You can copy the standard configuration, just copying from a new project. Of course you have to customize your file with your dependencies and your configuration.