# Android Studio .gradle xml files deleted

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I mistakenly deleted gradle values.xml files . As a result i am getting the following error (see the link)

[image]
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDEmC.png (Android Studio Log)
                               I tried reverting back the change but it is not working . I also tried rebuilding, cleaning project but it is not helping .Also this error is showing in all my projects . I believe if i can remove the app-compact , design files and then re download it , problem should go but i cant figure it out how to do . Is there any way to fix this error ?

Comment: Please see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307280/how-to-regenerate-build-gradle-file-after-deleting and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272923/how-to-restore-build-gradle-and-gradle-folder Hope this will help you

Comment: It is not working . In my case my .gradle file is not deleted instead some lines are deleted .

Comment: If somehow i can restore these lines (restore option is not helping) , it might help