# Failed to sync Gradle project

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, google-project-tango

How can I fix this error? I am new to Android and I would like to build an example Project Tango AR code inside Android Studio.

```
Failed to sync Gradle project 'java_augmented_reality_example'
Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-19' in: /Users/mona/Library/Android/sdk
Open Android SDK Manager
```

[image]

Here's the code I am using:

```
git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java.git
```

Comment: You can check the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error

Comment: Go to the SDK manager and make sure that SDK 19 is downloaded

Answer (score 0):

The error was fixed by downloading Android SDK 19 from Android SDK manager as shown in the screenshots below:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ii shows that Android Studio lack local 19 API.You can download this API with SDK or change compile API to anothor.Open build.gradle and change targetSdkVersion.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tony.newsapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```