# How to solve this android gradle issue?

Tags: android, gradle

Error:Unable to load class 'com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectSyncData'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error

Comment: `File > Invalidate cache / Restart` if using Android Studio, then re-try.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded latest gradle version and pointed out its location in File -> Settings -> Build, Execution & Deployment -> Gradle -> Gradle home

Gave the path to latest downloaded gradle version it seems that this might have solved this problem.

Thanks all by the way for replying

Answer (score 0):

Follow following steps:-

1. File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
2. Shutdown Android Studio
3. Rename/remove .gradle
4. Restart Android Studio let it download all the Gradle
5. Gradle build
6. Rebuild project