# android studio 2.1.2 c++ code complete

Tags: android-studio, android-source

I am not getting C++ code complete to work in Android Studio 2.1.2.  I imported an existing aosp project with custom c++ and java modules.  Android Studio can code complete the java code but not the c++.

I see the following error on top of the C++ file:
"The file has been added after the last project sync with Gradle.  Please sync the project again for the NDK support to work properly."
"The project 'XXXX' is not a Gradle-based project."

I tried importing the project 2 different ways with no luck:
1.  Generate an *.isr file and opened that.  Pointed to NDK home.  Then "Invalidate Caches/Restart"
2.  from "Welcome to android Studio"
    a.  Import project(Eclipse, Gradle, etc.)
    b.  Select project to import
    c.  Import project from external model "Gradle"
    d.  Point Gradle home: "/opt/android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.10"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To compile c/c++ files in Android Studio you should use NDK and then make calls from java to your native code using JNI.

Drop your native files into src/main/jni/ folder.

And then configure gradle. 
Something like:

```
android {
        ndk {
        moduleName "mylibrary"
        ldLibs  "m", "log", "android"
} }
```

You would need to download and config ndk.

There are a lot sources how to do it, google "how to use c++ file in android studio". [Top link from search](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-code-in-an-android-app-with-the-ndk/)

Or you could compile your c code not in Android Studio as .so library with proper JNI signatures(using javah) and drop it in JNIlibs folder.

Comment: your comments let me to the answer that fixed my issue:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error