# Gradle sync failed: com.android.builder.model.AndroidProject.getProjectType()I

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My Gradle sync fails with the following error message in the log:

```
Gradle sync failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.builder.model.AndroidProject.getProjectType()I
```

or sometimes I get this error instead:

```
Gradle sync failed: com.android.builder.model.AndroidProject.getProjectType()I
```

And this error pop up (The yellowish box that pops up at top of the gradle file in android studio):

```
Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.
```

I had the same issue a few days earlier, but I just clicked *file/Invalid Caches/restart* and the Gradle sync succeded.However, the gradle fail has returned again today.

I have tried everything [suggested here in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error) and other SO posts but nothing seem to work, the error is still there.

Is there any suggestions on other things I can try to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get rid of this problem now. It seems it had something to do with the latest Android Studio.

I downloaded `2.3 Beta 1` from the **Canary Channel**, and that's where the problem was.

I went back to using `2.3 Canary 3` from the **Canary Channe**l, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Delete after backup folder `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`
and unzip Beta Android Studio zip file into that folder. Hope it help!