# Android Studio 2.3 Gradle sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I use Kali Linux and I installed the latest Android Studio stable release (Android Studio 2.3.1 *build #AI-162.3871768*). When i use the simple Hello World App Template to test that all is working, I obain this error:

```
Gradle sync failed:
com.android.builder.model.AndroidProject.getProjectType()
```

I tried to remove *.gradle* and *.androidstudio* folders.

I checked that it is updated, and I saw these lines from the log:

```
2017-05-08 16:06:49,558 [ 258499]   INFO -
.AndroidModuleModelDataService - Failed to set up modules in project
'Test'  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
com.android.builder.model.AndroidProject.getProjectType()I
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.getProjectType(AndroidModuleModel.java:694)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.android.AndroidFacetModuleSetupStep.configureFacet(AndroidFacetModuleSetupStep.java:83)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.android.AndroidFacetModuleSetupStep.doSetUpModule(AndroidFacetModuleSetupStep.java:61)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.android.AndroidFacetModuleSetupStep.doSetUpModule(AndroidFacetModuleSetupStep.java:41)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.ModuleSetupStep.setUpModule(ModuleSetupStep.java:35)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.AndroidModuleSetup.setUpModule(AndroidModuleSetup.java:48)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.data.service.AndroidModuleModelDataService.setUpModule(AndroidModuleModelDataService.java:82)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.data.service.AndroidModuleModelDataService.importData(AndroidModuleModelDataService.java:70)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.data.service.ModuleModelDataService$1.run(ModuleModelDataService.java:71)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$Simple.run(WriteCommandAction.java:167)
    .............
```

*I have 2 build.gradle*:

**build.gradle (Project: Test)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hoper.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Show us the `build.gradle` of the `AndroidModuleModelDataService` module.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I added some files to the question.

Comment: What is your android studio version? What is your gradle version?

Comment: Have you see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449013/gradle-sync-failed-com-android-builder-model-androidproject-getprojecttypei?